# Can I change to a CustomUser model after the initial migration? Or I should've done it at the start of the project?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add custom user model mid project, and I might remember reading somewhere that you can't do that or that it isn't easy to do so, is that true? What can I do now?

Comment: You can do it, and it isn't easy to do - I do happen to have a [blog post](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2019/04/26/how-switch-custom-django-user-model-mid-project/) still open from doing it not long ago..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to proceed with this is to make another model which uses an OneToOneField to the user model. For example I am making this model to add fields like profile_pic, Your_website.

models.py

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    Your_website = models.URLField(blank = True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_pics", blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

On your next migration it will ask you to provide a default for the user field so remember to do so.

**By this method you can create a custom user model with the existing user model.**